# Image is transparently overlapping text

Tags: css, positioning, transparency, z-index

On [this webpage I'm developing](http://sarahheard.co.uk/new/test/test.php) the letters "Sa" and "Flu" are somehow both behind and in front of an image.

The image isn't fully on top - there's no transparency in the image, so if it was then the text simply wouldn't be visible.

However the image clearly isn't underneath either.

What's going on here?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transparency comes from the `#maincontainer` which has opacity set to 0.92, which causes all of its content to be slightly transparent, unless your specify something else on the child-elements.

```
#maincontainer {
   margin: 0;
   padding-left: 14px;
   padding-right: 14px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   text-align: justify;
   opacity: 0.92; /* Your transparency */
}
```

**Update:**

Setting `z-index` is not sufficient if the elements you want to position the element in relation to aren't positioned. z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). This is why the [solution suggested by Truth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122120/678801), setting the header to `position: relative;` works. Now the image can be placed underneath the text using z-index.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `position: relative` on the `header` div seems to solve the issue, that's because `z-index` doesn't work on elements which are statically positioned (default, no `position` value), as explained further on [Christofer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122133/871050).

The transparency propagates from a higher container, (in this case `#maincontainer`).

Comment: Took the liberty to elaborate a bit further on why your solution works in an additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is transparency because you've set an opacity on the picture.

Removing the opacity here :

```
#maincontainer {
    opacity: 0.92; /*< remove this line*/
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Resolves the problem.